# Can anyone make me clear about definition of inverse transformation?

Tags: linear-transformations

If I have T:V->V

T maps x in V onto itself, which implies that Range of T is V itself.

So, does that mean that

inverse of T : V->V ?

and if then, inverse of T is same as T ?

If T maps onto itself, T is a identify function.

But, there are two different inverses, right and left.

So, for T: V->V

are right inverse and left inverse same?

Comment: "So, does that mean that inverse of T : V->V ?" 
This looks incomplete, what do you tried to ask?

Comment: Take for example $T(x,y) = (3x,8y)$, its true that $T(1,1) = (3,8)$ but not true that $T(3,8) = (1,1)$, therefore $T^{-1}\neq T$.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ maps $V$ to $V$, and $T$ is invertible, then yes, it is true that $T^{-1}$ also maps $V$ to $V$, but that does not mean that $T = T^{-1}$.

Comment: and for that transformation, left and right inverses are the same ?

Comment: @aaa By definition, if a transformation is invertible, then its left and right inverses are the same.

Comment: If there is left inverse, it is same as right inverse. But, is it possible that there is one left inverse(obvious it is unique) and more than one right inverse?

Comment: @aaa no.  If there is a left inverse and a right inverse, then both are unique and equal to each other.  If $S$ is a left inverse and $U$ is a right inverse, then $U = (ST)U = S(TU) = S$.

Answer (score 0):

well if $T(x)=x$ then $T=I$ (identity map), and its both left and right inverse are same i.e. $I$

$1)$  A function possesses a left inverse if and only if it’s injective.

$2)$  A function possesses a right inverse if and only if it’s surjective.

and function has both sided inverse iff bijective.

As to you doubt, you can use that set of all invertible operators form the group $GL(V) \cong GL(n,F)$ if dim$V$ is finite, and left and right inverses in a group are same, see any algebra book for that, say Gallian.

Comment: what about the other functions besides t(x)=x, which transform onto itself? are there left and right inverses same?

Comment: yeah both are same